# Wordpress, can't connect to FTPS (SSL)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ftps

I'm trying to connect to my server by FTPS (SSL) from Wordpress. But I'm getting failed to connect.

I'm using a different port, 2222 instead of 22. I can connect to the server with Filezilla or other programs but not with Wordpress.

And yes I'm inserting the port to hostname.

```
Hostname
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2222

FTP/SSH Username
xxxxxxxxxx

FTP/SSH Password
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Connection Type
FTPS (SSL)
```

Error

```
Failed to connect to FTP Server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2222
```

Comment: Do you have any custom parameter in Filezille connection? such as "explit ftp over tls" or "active/passive mode" ?

Comment: look at this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-connect-to-hosting-ftp-ftps/

Comment: @Elvin85 No I'm not using any custom parameters in Filezilla. The Transfer mode is Default.

Comment: Then you might need to check if your server enabled "outbound request for 2222 port" or not. How to check it? It is possible with simple commands in SSH command-line . If you don't have enough experience on it, just contact your hosting provider. FYI, Azure servers disables all custom outbound ports by default.

Comment: @Elvin85 I searched the ssh command but didn't find anything. I'm hosting the server myself.

Comment: Why do you need FTP connection? If it is for installing themes/plugins, then you might have wrong filesystem ownership. You can easily solve it by CHOWN commands. Or by changing their permissions to 0777. Then it will not ask any FTP credentials.

Comment: @Elvin85  I need the FTP connection for easier plugin/theme download/update. I can just copy paste the files in folders, but It would be alot easier if I could use ftp. I'm pretty sure my filesystem ownership is fine

Comment: If filesystem ownership is fine, you should not need FTP, all install/update/delete should be through PHP only. No any FTP, no any manual copy/paste.   For example go to wp-admin/theme-editor.php - do you see BLUE SAVE button under the code? If you don't see it, it means there is a problem with file permissions or ownerships. \

Comment: @Elvin85 BLUE SAVE button? Do u mean that I can edit it and after that save it? If so, yes I can modify it.

Comment: Then why do you need FTP? i just can't get it :) Because if there is no problem with file editing, then no FTP is needed for update/install/delete.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, but end up using `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` in `wp-config.php` avoiding FTP connection all together. It works faster and is normally used by WordPress hosting providers.